# How to stop the background moving when moving a text downwards in bulma?

Tags: html, css, background, bulma

I wrote this code:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet"     href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.4/css/bulma.min.css">
  <title>Website</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="icon.ico?v=2"  />
</head>
<body class = "has-background-success">
   <h1 class = "is-size-2 mt-2 pr-6 has-text-white">Website</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The background of the website is green. When moving the heading a bit down using mt-2 the background also moves down a bit revealing the white underneath it. How do I fix this?

Any Help Will Be Greatly Appreciated, Thank You.

Comment: As always with styling issues, a picture would be helpful.